# All UpdatePanels on page updating on __doPostBack

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I am experiencing off behaviour when trying to update an UpdatePanel via JavaScript when multiple UpdatePanels are on the page.

Will try to keep it short:

- I'm already setting the UpdateMode to Conditional
- I am passing in the correct ClientID of the UpdatePanel into the __EventTarget
- In the code-behind, I am successfully able to find the target control

But for some reason, the OnLoad of every UpdatePanel on the page is fired.

Below is a snippet of code - any idea why this is happening?

Ascx:

```
<div class="updatePanelWrapper">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" RenderMode="Inline" OnLoad="UpdatePanel1Load"
    runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
<div class="updatePanelWrapper">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" UpdateMode="Conditional" RenderMode="Inline" OnLoad="UpdatePanel2Load"
    runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div>
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server">
            </asp:Panel>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

CodeBehind:

```
protected void UpdatePanel1Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdatePanelLoad(sender, e);
}

protected void UpdatePanel2Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdatePanelLoad(sender, e);
}

protected void UpdatePanelLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // if only a async postback then load the control
    if (ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).IsInAsyncPostBack)
    {
        // Some Logic ...
    }
}
```

JavaScript (where I'm triggering the ASYNC PostBack):

```
var updatePanelWrappers = $(".updatePanelWrapper");
var availableWrapper = updatePanelWrappers[0];
var updatePanelElement = $(availableWrapper).children()[0];
var updatePanelId = $(updatePanelElement).attr("id");

window.__doPostBack(updatePanelId, "Some Arguments...");
```

Answer (score 0):

With an UpdatePanel callback the page still goes through most of its lifecycle; which includes all of the Load events.